# MongoDB join two complex collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I got two collections

1. data

```json
{
  _id: ObjectId('123'),
  uuid: '123abc'
  content: 'hello'
}

{
  _id: ObjectId('456'),
  uuid: '123abc'
  content: 'hi'
}
```

2. history

```json
{
 _id: ObjectId('xxx'),
 uuid: '123abc'
 data: [{path: '/hello.json', objectId: '123'}, {path: '/hi.json', objectId: '456'}]
}
```

I want

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('123'),
  uuid: '123abc'
  content: 'hello'
  path: '/hello.json'
}

{
  _id: ObjectId('456'),
  uuid: '123abc'
  content: 'hi'
  path: '/hi.json'
}
```

Step:

1. use the uuid to find the second json
2. use the objectId of the second json data array element to locate the first json

Does anyone who knows how to write the MongoDB operations to join the two collections

[the result after the second stage is finished](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPDmx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Aggregation Framework:

- `$lookup` - To fetch data from the **history** collection
- `$set` with `$first` - To get the first element from the `history` property, since the `$lookup` always return an array
- `$set` with `$filter` - To create a `path_element` property that has the filtered history based on the document `_id`.
- `$project` - to project the data as expected output.

```js
db.data.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "history",
      "localField": "uuid",
      "foreignField": "uuid",
      "as": "history"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "history": {
        "$first": "$history"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      path_element: {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$history.data",
          "cond": {
            $eq: [
              {
                $toString: "$_id"
              },
              "$$this.objectId"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      uuid: 1,
      content: 1,
      path: {
        "$getField": {
          "field": "path",
          "input": {
            $first: "$path_element"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Li099JjeurO)